# Sequence of Chinese characters for keeping track of days of the year

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, traditional-characters, word-lists, calendar

I wonder whether anyone has knowledge of any sequence of Chinese characters used for describing such a list (one character for each of the 365 days in a year).

Such a list could be memorized by people who need to carry out very long tasks and need a reference to remember the day of the year for each task (and use it, if so needed (I don't know whether this would even be painful or not), to memorize what they've done each day of the year.

The list, in any case, would make nice entries in agendas and calendars.

I have never used such a list. So I don't know, if, and how, such a list would be useful.

My only concern, is, that anyone using such a list would have a concern with their days being counted. ... (but on the other hand it would juggle memory (and, could even, be useful, to stimulate the minds of seniors (giving, them, a tool, to construct links, with what they did (and perhaps remember dates))).

Again, I don't know whether this could be a good idea (but, the odds, are, yes).

I thought I'd exploit the fact that Chinese has many characters, and that these are stimukating (perhaps, even, of course!, particularly, stimulating), to make it the most appropriate language for constructing such a list.

Can anyone help me find such a list.

If, it does not exist, could anyone help me construct one.

Such, many, thanks.

Great greetings.

May life, bring, the best, to you/upon you.

Thanks.

Comment: One character that represents a day? Do you have examples in your language?

Comment: I can't imagine how such a list would work, its seems very different from anything I can imagine in chinese or english.  I think 99% of people in either language would simply number the days, aka 181 for the 181st day etc.  if you wanted to make one I'm sure you could but what would it be based on? I can't imagine any way to make any characters logical in order without more context.  even if you wanted to repurpose the old date system for each day it would be more than one character each and lots of repeat characters-- basically just writing the dates before modern calendars.

Comment: We already have such a list, and it's called the calendar. The year is divided into months and months into days. Instead of your idea of one character representing one day, we have a few for each day N 月 N 日. It works for most people, so I don't really see any point inventing a new one.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it also means people need to remember an arbitrary list of 366 characters in sequence. Not something you want to make people do nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

> sequence of Chinese characters used for describing such a list (one character for each of the 365 days in a year

**no** such list lah  he closest thing is [代日韻目](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BB%A3%E6%97%A5%E9%9F%BB%E7%9B%AE) which used 32 characters to represent 1 - 31 day of each month.

> Such a list could be memorized by people who need to carry out very long tasks and need a reference to remember the day of the year for each task

an interesting idea, though, . . . not practically useful

prior to advise, i assume you’re using gregorian calendar (it’s possible, to adjust the list for other calendar systems, but, . . .)

the straightforward method is using characters from [千字文](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%83%E5%AD%97%E6%96%87), a text containing one thousand non-repeated characters in **traditional chinese**, so:

01 jan - 天

02 jan - 地

03 jan - 玄

04 jan - 黃

05 jan - 宇

06 jan - 宙

07 jan - 洪

08 jan - 荒

then, you need one special character for 29th february.

however, i think that adjusting famous seven char poem (七言古詩) for the list is, easier to memorise (but you need to find characters for replacing repeated characters) such as [長恨歌](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E9%95%B7%E6%81%A8%E6%AD%8C), so:

01 jan - 漢

02 jan - 皇

03 jan - 重

04 jan - 色

05 jan - 思

06 jan - 傾

07 jan - 國

08 jan - 御

again, you need one special character for 29th february.

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. Can you please tell me what 七言古詩 is? I am not aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it only a seven word old poem if there are more than seven words in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the combinations of

天干（10）：甲、乙、丙、丁、戊、己、庚、辛、壬、癸

地支（12）：子、丑、寅、卯、辰、巳、午、未、申、酉、戌、亥

A long long time ago, the Chinese use those characters to remember years, months, days, and hours.

They also use 地支 to remember their age. They use 12 kinds of animals for each of the 12 years, which is called 十二生肖.

十二生肖, 子（鼠）、丑（牛）、寅（虎）、卯（兔）、辰（龙）、巳（蛇）、午（马）、未（羊）、申（猴）、酉（鸡）、戌（狗）、亥（猪）

Comment: That's not unique though. There are 60 combinations, and then the cycle starts over.

Answer (score 0):

[干支](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle) is used to number years, months, days and hours. It is a cycle of sixty terms.

[千字文](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand_Character_Classic) is used to number items of a large quantity, such as rooms in a hotel. It is a text that contains exactly one thousand characters, each used only once.

If you want just one character for each day of the year, 千字文 is very suitable.

However, the traditional way of numbering days is 干支. With 干支, you need 4 characters to specify a day in a year (2 characters for the month, 2 for the day). This way, you don't have to maintain your own system, because there are many free online converters. They are even present in calendars.

[image]